# On contact : change history (logging) is empty

Tags: logging

On contacts, the "Change log" tab is empty. It used to show the contact fields updated, with previous and new value.

I checked the following :

- I have enabled **logging** at Administer - System Settings - Misc.
- Contact Reports - Contact Logging Report (Summary) : works fine

Any idea why I can't see the change history on the contact page, although I can see it in a report ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the browser dev tools console/network tabs. I'll bet there's an error listed there.

Comment: Indeed, in "Issues" of Chrome dev tools I found this :

-----------
Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform
A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.

Comment: Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.
1 source
jquery-ui.min.js:1
https://[ourdomain].org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js